# What is the operating system (OS) of Web3 apps and decentralized applications?

Tags: operating-system, blockchain, solidity

Is a blockchain the operating system (OS) of Web3 apps? I am trying to understand what constitutes the OS for Web apps.

In my understanding; apps interact with the OS, and the OS interacts with the machine.

Since a blockchain is a supercomputer of sorts, what would be considered to be the OS of Web3 apps?

In my understanding; apps interact with the OS, and the OS interacts with the machine.

If the blockchain is a computer, I can't seem to understand what the OS would be in a Web3 architecture.

Comment: This question is too broad and arguably off-topic here. Which application are you talking about? Most run on Linux or Windows operating systems. Web applications run on a web server, which is a computer designed for one-to-many network connections.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a "blockchain OS" would be vaporware built out of pure hype that relies on the fact that if it never exists nobody finds out that it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

They say that OS for Web3 is yet to be developed.
For example, such opinion has Moralis https://academy.moralis.io/blog/blockchain-operating-system-explained

They are not the only ones. Similar things trying to achieve for example https://www.alchemy.com and many others there. We live in a beautiful time of the beginning of something new :)